# Can't use react hooks in a dynamically imported component (nextJs v 13)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

## **What I'm trying to achieve is the following**

I have a db where all my tools are stored, along with a slug.
On pages/tool/[slug] I get a slug from the params, and fetch the tool using that slug I also export a generatedMetadata with the name of the tool as the title of the page.

Then with the slug for example "color-picker" I transform it to, ColorPicker and import the right component like such:

```js
const Component = dynamic(() => import(`@components/tools/${componentName}`));
```

So that for each tool, it goes under components/tools and gets the right one and renders it.

Now each component is different, some may need react hooks, some don't, so I can't pass anything from the page.jsx, cause it would just be a mess

I could create a page for each tool for example /pages/tool/color-picker but that wouldn't be efficient, I want to have something that gets the tool and sends metadata without having to do manually each time Sort of a layout But not a layout

## Here's how I import the components:

```
export default async function Tool({ params }) {
  const tool = await getTool(params?.slug);

  const componentName = slugToPascalCase(tool.slug);

  const Component = dynamic(() => `@components/tools/${componentName}`);

  return (
    <>
      <main className="flex flex-col w-full h-auto justify-center items-center px-4 py-16 sm:px-6 sm:py-24 lg:px-8 lg:py-32 font-poppins">
        <ToolsHeader tool={tool} />
      </main>
      <div className="w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-4 px-4 pb-6 lg:px-16">
        <Component.default />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

## Error I'm getting

[Click here to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sas7x.png)

I tried importing the components manually and it works just fine, something happens when importing dynamically that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

change  `<Component.default />` to  `<Component/>`.

Comment: Didn't work, still the same issue

Comment: any update on this @Expensiveee . I have run into a similar problem where i am trying to import a separately bundled react component